VExpansionPanel useGroup injection error after upgrading
We use Vue 3 app (Vite) with Vuetify. After upgrading the package to the latest version, we get the following error:

The code looks as following:
<v-col md3>
    <v-expansion-panel class="mb-3">
        <v-expansion-panel-text hide-actions ripple>
            <div @click="create" class="form-action" id="create-btn" slot="header">
                <v-icon>add_circle</v-icon>
                Создать
            </div>
        </v-expansion-panel-text>
        <v-expansion-panel-text hide-actions ripple>
            <div @click="refresh" class="form-action" id="refresh-btn" slot="header">
                <v-icon>mdi-reload</v-icon>
                Обновить
            </div>
        </v-expansion-panel-text>
    </v-expansion-panel>

How to get rid of this error?

Check the vuetify 3 documentation.  The code examples all work, so model your code after them.  The expectation based on all the examples is that the panel related components should all be wrapped inside of <v-expansion-panels>.

@yoduh It helped. Please, write your comment as answer and I'll check it as correct one. Thanks.
